# How do I display the text at the bottom of the icon on the nav bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating my first website and i'm currently stuck on how I can place the text below my gift icon. With the icon also centred. Any help would be very much appreciated!

This is what I currently have, as you can see the gift icon is inline with the text "vouchers"
[image]

This is what I am trying to get - with the icon above the text
[image]

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #393838;
    color: white;
}

.navbar {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    color: white;
    display: inline-flexbox;
    background-color: #393838;
}

.navbar-brand {
padding-left: 2rem;
}

/* navbar links font color */
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color:white;
}

/* hoover color navbar */
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.acitve,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #fdb629;
}


.top-content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 10rem;
}

.top-content .carousel-control-prev {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.top-content .carousel-control-next {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.top-content .carousel-caption {
    padding-top: 200px;
    color:white;
    
}

.top-content .carousel-indicators li {
    width: 1px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


.d-block {
height:800px
}

.footer{
    background-color: #393838;
  
}

.bi {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
}

.bi.bi-gift:hover{
color: gold;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <img class="img-fluid ml-3" src="media/hotel-logo.png" alt="brand-logo" width="190" height="190">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-menu"
                    aria-controls="navbar-menu" aria-expanded="flase" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </a>

            <!-- menu items -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"></div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Rooms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Spa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Casino</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dining</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Entertainment</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Luxury Packages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Weddings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- icon and button in navbar -->
                <div class="">
                    <a class="bi bi-gift" href="#" aria-hidden="true"><span>Vouchers</span></a>
                    <button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-warning ">Book Now</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
        </header> <!-- end of navbar-->

        <!-- Top content -->
        <div class="top-content">
            <!-- Carousel -->
            <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="media/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide-img-1">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Paradise Awaits...</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="media/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide-img-2">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Relax and Rest</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="media/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide-media-3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end image slider -->

    
        <div class="container video-text ">
            <br>

<h1> ABOUT US</h1>
 <hr
                class="ml-4 mb-4 mt-0"
                style="width: 130px; background-color: #c5a651; height: 2px;"
                />
<p>Inspired by the villages of Europe, AAA Five Diamond Bellagio overlooks a Mediterranean-blue lake with fountains performing a magnificent ballet. Escape into an otherworldly plane of dance, music and acrobatics with “O” by Cirque du Soleil — aquatic theater in our Parisian-style opera house. 
    Among all the luxury resorts, artsy clubs, and romantic restaurants, there’s one place that stands out - Bellagio Hotel and Casino. Bellagio, built by Steve Wynn and operated by MGM Resorts, is a synonym of opulence. From spacious rooms to mesmerizing views, Bellagio offers an outstanding experience.</p>
    </div>

<!-- video -->
<div class="video-container embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
  <video controls><source src="media/promo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>

<h1 class="pt-5"style="text-align:center;">Customer Reviews</h1>
 <hr
                class="mb-4 mt-0 mx-auto"
                style="width: 200px; background-color: #c5a651; height: 2px;"
                />

<!-- Begin widget code -->
<div class="elfsight-app-f5e372b9-39aa-46f0-a073-9b4fb63f7f45" ></div>
<script src="https://apps.elfsight.com/p/platform.js" defer></script>


<!-- footer -->
<footer>

    
    <div class="py-2 text-center" style="background-color: #c5a651;">
            
        <h5>Get connected with us on social media<h5>

            <div class="d-flex"></div>
                  <a href="" class="" style="padding-right:15px">
          <i class="bi bi-instagram "></i>
        </a>
                   <a href="" class="" style="padding-right:15px">
          <i class="bi bi-facebook"></i>
        </a>
                   <a href="" class="" style="padding-right:15px">
          <i class="bi bi-twitter"></i>
        </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="">

 <div class="container text-center text-md-start mt-5">
        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-4">

            <!-- Content -->
            <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold">Directions</h6>
            <hr
                class="mb-2 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto"
                style="width: 60px; background-color: #c5a651; height: 2px"
                />
            <p><a style="color: white;" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bellagio+Hotel+%26+Casino/@36.1129498,-115.1786954,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m8!3m7!1s0x80c8c430cb5147bd:0x82f2c7c5d9d10d84!5m2!4m1!1i2!8m2!3d36.1129455!4d-115.1765067"
              target="_blank">3600 S Las Vegas Blvd, Las Vegas, NV 89109, United States
            </a></p>
          </div>
    

       <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-md-0 mb-4">
            
            <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold">Awards</h6>
            <hr
                class="mb-2 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto "
                style="width: 60px; background-color: #c5a651; height: 2px"
                />
      <div class="container">
                <img class="img-fluid " src="media/Award1.png" alt="brand-logo" width="100" height="100">
                <img class="img-fluid " src="media/Award2.png" alt="brand-logo" width="100" height="100">
                <img class="img-fluid p-2 " src="media/Award3.png" alt="brand-logo" width="100" height="100">

       </div>
          </div>


<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-md-0 mb-4">
    
            <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold">Contact</h6>
            <hr
                class="mb-2 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto"
                style="width: 60px; background-color: #c5a651; height: 2px"
                />
            <p><i class="bi bi-telephone mr-3"></i>702.693.7111</p>
            <p><i class="bi bi-envelope mr-3"></i> <a style="color: white;" href="mailto:paradise-hotel@interprise.com">paradise-hotel@interprise.com</a></p>
            <p><i class="bi bi-calendar-check mr-3"></i>702.693.7222</p>
            <p><i class="bi bi-printer mr-3"></i>01 234 567 89</p>
          </div>

    </div>
    </section>
</footer>
        
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.4.8/swiper-bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-9bpSJxAAJvmeQaFXUNEj1/0eGdUshcOiO8M5PrRX0WT3S8s7omJGVe8sL1VoePTYPSariYUqnYJ/XbDwH4hbrA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.4.5/swiper-bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-1LlEYE0qExJ/GUfAJ0k2K2fB5sIvMv/q6ueo3syohvQ3ElWDQVSMUOf39cxaDWHtNu7M6lF6ZC1H6A1m3SvheA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try applying these styles:

```
#navbar-menu div {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap: 1rem;
}

#navbar-menu div a {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #393838;
    color: white;
}

.navbar {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    color: white;
    display: inline-flexbox;
    background-color: #393838;
}

.navbar-brand {
padding-left: 2rem;
}

/* navbar links font color */
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color:white;
}

/* hoover color navbar */
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.acitve,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #fdb629;
}


.top-content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 10rem;
}

.top-content .carousel-control-prev {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.top-content .carousel-control-next {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.top-content .carousel-caption {
    padding-top: 200px;
    color:white;
    
}

.top-content .carousel-indicators li {
    width: 1px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


.d-block {
height:800px
}

.footer{
    background-color: #393838;
  
}

.bi {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
}

.bi.bi-gift:hover{
color: gold;
}

  .iconAndButton a {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <img class="img-fluid ml-3" src="media/hotel-logo.png" alt="brand-logo" width="190" height="190">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-menu"
                    aria-controls="navbar-menu" aria-expanded="flase" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </a>

            <!-- menu items -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"></div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Rooms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Spa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Casino</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dining</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Entertainment</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Luxury Packages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Weddings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- icon and button in navbar -->
                <div class="iconAndButton">
                    <a class="bi bi-gift" href="#" aria-hidden="true"><span>Vouchers</span></a>
   
                </div>
          <button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-warning ">Book Now</button>

            </div>
        </nav>
        </header> <!-- end of navbar-->

        <!-- Top content -->
        <div class="top-content">
            <!-- Carousel -->
            <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="media/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide-img-1">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Paradise Awaits...</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="media/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide-img-2">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Relax and Rest</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="media/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="slide-media-3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end image slider -->

    
        <div class="container video-text ">
            <br>

<h1> ABOUT US</h1>
 <hr
                class="ml-4 mb-4 mt-0"
                style="width: 130px; background-color: #c5a651; height: 2px;"
                />
<p>Inspired by the villages of Europe, AAA Five Diamond Bellagio overlooks a Mediterranean-blue lake with fountains performing a magnificent ballet. Escape into an otherworldly plane of dance, music and acrobatics with “O” by Cirque du Soleil — aquatic theater in our Parisian-style opera house. 
    Among all the luxury resorts, artsy clubs, and romantic restaurants, there’s one place that stands out - Bellagio Hotel and Casino. Bellagio, built by Steve Wynn and operated by MGM Resorts, is a synonym of opulence. From spacious rooms to mesmerizing views, Bellagio offers an outstanding experience.</p>
    </div>

<!-- video -->
<div class="video-container embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
  <video controls><source src="media/promo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>

<h1 class="pt-5"style="text-align:center;">Customer Reviews</h1>
 <hr
                class="mb-4 mt-0 mx-auto"
                style="width: 200px; background-color: #c5a651; height: 2px;"
                />

<!-- Begin widget code -->
<div class="elfsight-app-f5e372b9-39aa-46f0-a073-9b4fb63f7f45" ></div>
<script src="https://apps.elfsight.com/p/platform.js" defer></script>


<!-- footer -->
<footer>

    
    <div class="py-2 text-center" style="background-color: #c5a651;">
            
        <h5>Get connected with us on social media<h5>

            <div class="d-flex"></div>
                  <a href="" class="" style="padding-right:15px">
          <i class="bi bi-instagram "></i>
        </a>
                   <a href="" class="" style="padding-right:15px">
          <i class="bi bi-facebook"></i>
        </a>
                   <a href="" class="" style="padding-right:15px">
          <i class="bi bi-twitter"></i>
        </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="">

 <div class="container text-center text-md-start mt-5">
        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-4">

            <!-- Content -->
            <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold">Directions</h6>
            <hr
                class="mb-2 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto"
                style="width: 60px; background-color: #c5a651; height: 2px"
                />
            <p><a style="color: white;" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bellagio+Hotel+%26+Casino/@36.1129498,-115.1786954,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m8!3m7!1s0x80c8c430cb5147bd:0x82f2c7c5d9d10d84!5m2!4m1!1i2!8m2!3d36.1129455!4d-115.1765067"
              target="_blank">3600 S Las Vegas Blvd, Las Vegas, NV 89109, United States
            </a></p>
          </div>
    

       <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-md-0 mb-4">
            
            <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold">Awards</h6>
            <hr
                class="mb-2 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto "
                style="width: 60px; background-color: #c5a651; height: 2px"
                />
      <div class="container">
                <img class="img-fluid " src="media/Award1.png" alt="brand-logo" width="100" height="100">
                <img class="img-fluid " src="media/Award2.png" alt="brand-logo" width="100" height="100">
                <img class="img-fluid p-2 " src="media/Award3.png" alt="brand-logo" width="100" height="100">

       </div>
          </div>


<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mx-auto mb-md-0 mb-4">
    
            <h6 class="text-uppercase fw-bold">Contact</h6>
            <hr
                class="mb-2 mt-0 d-inline-block mx-auto"
                style="width: 60px; background-color: #c5a651; height: 2px"
                />
            <p><i class="bi bi-telephone mr-3"></i>702.693.7111</p>
            <p><i class="bi bi-envelope mr-3"></i> <a style="color: white;" href="mailto:paradise-hotel@interprise.com">paradise-hotel@interprise.com</a></p>
            <p><i class="bi bi-calendar-check mr-3"></i>702.693.7222</p>
            <p><i class="bi bi-printer mr-3"></i>01 234 567 89</p>
          </div>

    </div>
    </section>
</footer>
        
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.4.8/swiper-bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-9bpSJxAAJvmeQaFXUNEj1/0eGdUshcOiO8M5PrRX0WT3S8s7omJGVe8sL1VoePTYPSariYUqnYJ/XbDwH4hbrA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.4.5/swiper-bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-1LlEYE0qExJ/GUfAJ0k2K2fB5sIvMv/q6ueo3syohvQ3ElWDQVSMUOf39cxaDWHtNu7M6lF6ZC1H6A1m3SvheA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I build this quickly with bootstrap 4.

For break ligne between the gift and his word, I use simply a `<br>` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/docs/4.6/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    Bootstrap
  </a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Rooms</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Spa</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dining</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Entertainment</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Luxury Packages</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Weddings</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="navbar-text">
      <button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Book Now</button>
      <button type="button" href="#" class="btn bg-transparent"><span class="bi bi-gift" aria-hidden="true"><span><br><span>Vouchers</span></button>
  </span>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```